# Any web server that supports the SSL null ciphers?

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl

I have an old device that connects to a HTTPS web page and downloads some content. I want that device to download content from a domain I control, but the client has a specific Root CA embedded and only connects if the SSL connection uses a certificate by this CA.

I can certainly fix this by altering the software on the client and replace the https URL with a HTTP one, removing all the HTTPS stuff from the connection.

However I'm searching for a way to make that work without modification of the client (only DNS edits) and now I've read from the "SSL null ciphers".

Could using one of the SSL ciphers without authentication (for example, `TLS_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL` or `TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA` possibly make this device accept my fake connection? Maybe it accepts these fake ciphers ...

But I have no idea (and haven't found much information on the internet) how I can get my web server to actually use these ciphers.

I'm currently using Apache and tried configuring these ciphers, but it didn't work and the documentation states that the null ciphers have been removed because they are insecure. However, I know that they are insecure and would like to use them anyways ...

Is there another web server which I could use to negotiate a null cipher with that client and hopefully make it connect to my server even though it has no valid cert?

In theory, if the device accepts these ciphers, that should work with the fake server since these ciphers don't authenticate the server, do they?

Comment: As you say - _if the device accepts these ciphers_. That'll be your biggest challenge. You could look at recompiling OpenSSL or similar to provide the ciphers for your server.  Before that, you could try using `openssl s_server -cipher <list>` to see if the client will connect with a null cipher.  You may need to compile OpenSSL for this command to work too.

Comment: And how can I make that openssl server use a null cipher? I tried `openssl s_server -key k.pem -cert c.pem -accept 443 -www` and the output didn't contain any of the null ciphers, and `-cipher TLS_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5` also didn't work. EDIT, OK, got the server to work with `-cipher ADH`. Lets see what the client says about these ...

Comment: Don't forget to comment/answer here - it'll be interesting to find out how it goes. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely that a device which enforces a specific root certificate, i.e. tries to enforce proper certificate validation, can be convinced to accept a handshake with no authentication at all. Usually the ciphers with anonymous authentication are not enabled on the client side.

Apart from that: a NULL cipher is a cipher without encryption which still might require authentication (like in TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA). What you are asking for are ciphers without authentication which still might do encryption (like TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA).

Comment: I have now tried both the NULL cipher and multiple ADH ciphers with the s_server command suggested by garethTheRed, but unfortunately, as you expected, the client didn't accept any of those. Well, I guess I still have to patch the client to connect to the fake server ...

Comment: If you do a packet capture you can see (for example in wireshark) which ciphers the client is offering to the server. Any cipher which is not offered in the ClientHello of the TLS handshake will not be accepted by the client.